# Raised floor in garage bedroom addition

Tags: subfloor

Do I need to raise the floor to slab height of existing living space (garage floor is 6" lower than living space. I would probably say "yes" due some kind of code for residential flooding. Haven't got a reply for the building dept. yet. Does it need to be concrete or can it be wood framed and insulated? I'm planning to add a bathroom. So this would be a critical issue.

Comment: Flooding? Where are you?

Comment: It may depend on your location. I see both room additions on the cement and raised. The raised may cost more at first but will make installing the bathroom easier and provide a "warmer" feeling floor.

Comment: Southern California.